# When should \n in Python 3.x be used?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand that `\n` in Python 3.x begins a newline in a string.

But in this exemplar case:

```
answer = int(input("What's 7 x 3?\n"))
if answer == 21:
    print("That's correct.")
else:
    print("That's incorrect.")
```

should it be used and why? Also, in what other situations would `\n` be used?

Comment: You use `\n` if you want the following output to be on a new line.

Comment: Did you run the code? Did you like what it looked like? newline is used whenever you want... well... new lines.

Comment: I don't understand why my question is being downvoted. It is a very reasonable question, despite the fact that it may be somewhat trivial.

Comment: @PeterWood, I know that.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted cause it's not a question. There is nothing to understand, no situations to use it or not. If you want a newline, you use \n, if you don't, you don't use it. Simple as that.

Comment: @BobZeBuilder Well, that's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` is the standard newline character across most operating systems. In python, as well as most other programming languages, `\n` is used to start a newline whether you are aware of it or not. In python for example

```
print "hello world"
```

actually appends a newline character to the string in question and prints it.

```
print "hello world\n",
```

will yield the same exact output as the "," prevents the newline character from being added. In python there are very few reasons to use `\n` as it is generally added for you. The two main cases where one is explicitly interesting in the newline character is:

1. Writing to files
2. Removing newlines when reading from files

When writing to a file, one needs to explicitly use `\n` to generate newlines in the file. For example:

```
with open("example.txt","w") as fout:
     fout.write("hello world\n")
```

and when reading in from a file:

```
with open("example.txt","r") as fin:
     for line in fin:
         print line.rstrip("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your terminal session with the program to look like:

```
What's 7 x 3?
21
That's correct.
```

then you should put the newline as you have. If you want it to look like:

```
What's 7 x 3? 21
That's correct.
```

then you should put a space at the end of the prompt instead of newline:

```
answer = int(input("What's 7 x 3? "))
```

Comment: About your last point - I forgot to add `int`, I'm quite a beginner. I've made the appropriate changes to my question to correct that.